# Compare not working in Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am (finally) trying to upgrade to Eclipse Neon from Mars.2.  After installing SVN support and the SVNKit (1.8.14) connector, I am able to access my repository. However *Compare* is not working.

If I right click a file that I have modified, and choose *Compare with Base from Working Copy* a dialog is displayed saying **There are no differences between the selected inputs**.  If I choose *Team-> Synchronize with Repository*, the differences are shown in the Synchronization view.  Differences are also shown when comparing to Local History.

If I use Tortise SVN from File Explorer the differences from the current version to the Base Working version are shown.

Anyone have a solution / suggestion to restore this critical function?

Comment: I have the same issue with Eclipse Neon.2. Neither SVNKit 1.8.14 nor Native JavaHL 1.8.15 make my compare function working. FYI: this is already logged as a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=510192

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resolved with the Subversion provider 4.0 update :

Help -> Install new software -> Add 
 "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/4.0/update-site/" -> Select Subversion provider and update it.

Source :
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492534

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!