# Compare not working in Eclipse oxygen/photon

Tags: eclipse, subversive

This is same as this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722685/compare-not-working-in-eclipse-neon) but happening in new version (photon and oxygen) and the solution to use latest release (4.0.4 and higher) does not work.

I have installed latest Subversive stable [build](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/subversive/4.0/builds/Subversive-4.0.5.I20170425-1700.zip) (using archive method) **version Subversive-4.0.5.I20170425-1700.zip** as I have problem with proxy. And I have installed below connectors and tried to switch both.

- SVNKit 1.8.14
- Native JavaHL 1.9.3 version.

And when I compare files between branches or trunk and branch, although there are differences, it just shows "no differences found".

Comment: Can you please tell which version do you exactly use: Subversive and SVN Connector. The issue is related to Subversive respectively the SVN connector, so the Eclipse version doesn't matter here (please adapt the title). Both, SVNKit and JavaHL can be installed, but only one can be used. Which one do you use?

Comment: sorry the version is in link (not evident) so edited now. I tried swtich between these 2 connectors and same problem. My SVN server is running in 1.7. is that a problem ?

Comment: I also had the problem in the past. But with Subversive 4.0.5.I20170425-1700 and SVNKit 1.8.14 r10627 it is fixed and I cannot reproduce it anymore. The server is not involved when comparing with Base. Make sure you have successfully upgraded (_Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_).